# How can i apply a smooth expand transition to this vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The component below has a large amount of data and initially, this data is partially hidden. When the user clicks to expand, 'dataExpanded' property is set to true and 'data-not-expanded' class is removed, removing the overflow and limited height property. What i need is that, when removing the limited height, a smooth expand transition is displayed instead of abruptly changing the height of the component. How can i archieve it? I am using vue and vuetify but not sure if they can help since the transition isn't based on a simple v-if or v-show.

```
<car-page-data
            :class="{
              'data-not-expanded': !dataExpanded,
            }"
            :car="car"
          />
```

Style:

```
.data-not-expanded {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```